# Let's re-open this question, it is not a duplicate

Tags: support, closed-questions, specific-question, exact-duplicates

[Replace old Authenticator option in my Google account](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/171514/replace-old-authenticator-option-in-my-google-account?noredirect=1#comment160053_171514)

I added details to the question to make it clear why the "duplicate" that has been pointed at does not solve anything (and is actually not really related).

It seems that the question needs a re-open vote to be re-opened?

Comment: I have added the more explicit reason why it is not a duplicate in the question : [Edit: This question is different from a potential duplicate that was suggested about recovering a Google account. I went through that process and it worked. However I still cannot access my 2FA menu]

Answer (score 2):

The linked question "[How do I recover my Google (or Gmail) account, password, or username?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/52706/how-do-i-recover-my-google-or-gmail-account-password-or-username)" is the canonical post for Google account recovery questions.  The post is updated from time to time as information changes and I will be making some additional updates as a result of our discussion to make it more broadly reflect changes to the way these types of questions are typically framed versus when the original need for the canonical answer was identified.

Unfortunately, this site's model and standards don't provide a way to do troubleshooting using posts or comments.

I have however moved the question's comments to a [dedicated chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/147627/discussion-on-question-by-wip-replace-old-authenticator-option-in-my-google-acco) where I am willing to engage with you in more detail to better identify and perhaps even resolve your issue.  Other community members also have access to the [same chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/147627/discussion-on-question-by-wip-replace-old-authenticator-option-in-my-google-acco) and can weigh in to assist you.